# Working with polygons defined in the map window on Google EE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am starting out in Google Earth Engine though I have familiarity with QGIS and Google Earth and GIS in general; coding is definitely the weak point for me.

When I define a polygon in the map window using geometry imports > new layer, what is the easiest way to get those coordinates - or in general, the layer, into a ee.Geometry.Polygon([]) type statement in the script editor window?   I also notice that so far I have not been able to get those polygons to behave as assets - is there a way to do that too so that they show up in my assets tab?  I have the sense that this is probably very easy or I am not approaching the problem in the right way, however I feel the map window is such an easy way to interact with the code that I feel there must be an easy way.

---

Ok, now I see that the layer is automatically defined in the var section at the header of the script above.  But it still might be nice to know if I can move those features or feature collections into the Assets tab of the Google EE console at left?

Answer (score 1):

As you have seen, they appear in the var section at the top.  To save them as assets for use elsewhere, put single features into collections and then do:

```
Export.table.toAsset()
```

Check the documentation for the full details on the required parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you create geometry on the map, it becomes an [import](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/playground#imports) of your script. Imports of drawn geometry and imports of assets work the same way; they become variables you can refer to within the script. The name of each one is displayed after `var` in the imports section.

You **do not** need to convert geometry created in the geometry editor to an asset to use it in your script.

If you do want to so convert it (perhaps so that you can use it in multiple scripts), you will need to write an [`Export.table.toAsset()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#export.table.toasset) operation into that script. Since assets must be `FeatureCollection`s, not single geometries, first click on the gear icon that appears on hover for the import and set the "Import as" option to "FeatureCollection". (This means that each point or polygon you draw will be a separate feature in the collection, by default; you can write code to modify that if you need to.)